# How to clear localStorage when application is exited using ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to know how to determine when the application is exited using the hardware back button and eventually clear my localStorage data.

I need this for three primary reason:
1. Ask the user if he/she really wants to exit the application
2. Clear cached data
3. Force the user to always login anytime the application is started - because it's financial app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For determine when the application is exited. You have to reference [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/)

use registerBackButtonAction() method to handle backbutton hardware.

For example: In app.ts file

```
initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() =>{
    // 1. Ask the user if he/she really wants to exit the application
    //2. Clear cached data
    //3. Force the user to always login anytime the application is started
    return;
  });
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
});
}
```

Cheer!